# DRF ModelViewSet route get mixed in with ApiView route

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, routes

I have the following views:

```
class NotificationAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (CustomJWTAuthentication, SessionAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Notification.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.queryset.all()
        queryset = qs.filter(recipient=self.request.user.id)
        return queryset

class MarkAsReadView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = [CustomJWTAuthentication, SessionAuthentication]

    @swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters=[authorization])
    def post(self, request, notification_id):
        # mark single notification as read

class MarkAllAsReadView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = [CustomJWTAuthentication, SessionAuthentication]

    @swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters=[authorization])
    def post(self, request):
        #mark all notifications as read
```

and here is my urls.py routing:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register('notifications', NotificationAPI, basename='notifications')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    # notifications
    path('notifications/mark-as-read/<int:notification_id>',
         MarkAsReadView.as_view(), name='mark-as-read'), # this work
    path('notifications/mark-all-as-read',
         MarkAllAsReadView.as_view(), name='mark-all-as-read'), #this doesn't work
]
```

Currently whenever i call `mark-as-read` it work fine, but when i try to call `mark-all-as-read` api it always return the following `405` error:

```
{
  "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."
}
```

I checked and it seem like the notifications `ModelViewSet` routing messing up the other `mark-all-as-read ApiView` route.

I checked by commenting the `ModelViewSet` out and the `mark-all-as-read` now work.

Why is this happening? shouldn't routing be separate by `name` and `basename` ? Why it's when i call `mark-all-as-read` it go into the `ModelViewSet` route, but the `mark-as-read` work normally?

**UPDATE**:
i had update my `NotificationAPI` modelviewset api with custom route as suggestion from `Risadinha` but it's displaying serializer in body, how do i remove it? because there no need for `body data` in my `mark-as-read` and `mark-all-as-read` requests

My updated `NotificationAPI`

```
class NotificationAPI(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                      viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (CustomJWTAuthentication, SessionAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Notification.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer
    search_fields = ('verb__unaccent', 'description__unaccent')
    pagination_class = ListPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['unread']

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.queryset.all()
        queryset = qs.filter(recipient=self.request.user.id)
        return queryset

    @action(
        basename='mark-all-as-read',
        detail=False,
        methods=['post'],
        name='mark-all-as-read',
        url_path=r'mark-all-as-read',
        url_name='Mark All As Read'
    )
    def mark_all_as_read(self, request):
        #do some stuffs

    @action(
        basename='mark-as-read',
        detail=False,
        methods=['put'],
        name='mark-as-read',
        url_path=r'mark-as-read/(?P<pk>\d+)'
    )
    def mark_as_read(self, request, pk=None):
        #do some stuffs
```

Comment: The error sounds like the action gets routed to the detail endpoint (e.g. `/api/notifications/:notificationId` while it should be routed to `/api/notifications/`). Also, you could add both the `markAsRead` and `markAllAsRead` actions as methods with decorator `@action` to your `NotificationAPI`. See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Comment: @Risadinha i'm not familiar with the action decorator for custom method, will it work like this? `@action(detail=True, methods=['post'])` ? how do i write the url route?

Comment: now i notice that if i use modelviewset it will always put serializer in the new route i added too.. which i don't want